# matplotlib figures does not appear

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

matplotlib figures show up fine in Ipython3 (v 6.0.0) but won't appear in either the qtconsole 4.3.0, under python 3.4.6, or the notebook. for example, `plt.plot(range(7))` does not appear
and `plt.show()` does not help

However, if I do `%matplotlib inline` then I do get the plots in both the notebook and qtconsole.

Separate figure windows used to work for me and I can't figure it out.
thanks,